# How to solve 6 equaitons with 5 unknowns in matrix form

Tags: equation-solving

I am having 6 homogeneous equations with 5 unknowns. can we use NullSpace to solve for unknowns or what else the correct code i can write to solve these equations.

I have tried with **'NullSpace'** syntax. I have defined the coefficients in a matrix form which is 6 cross 5 matrix and i have named it as 'A'. Then I ve written the code as `NullSpace[A]`. It couldnt work out correctly. But in help centre it shows that NullSpace can be used to solve the rectangular matrix also like that.

I will be highly thankful if anyone can suggest me directions to solve this non - square matrix to find the unknowns as well as the eigen values.

Comment: You should include the  code you have written with your question and format it correctly here so it is readable. What is the definition for `A`? By the way, you should not start your variables with capital letters.